# How to check for duplicates in a list and save each email one by line in a file

Tags: javascript

I have a list like this:

```
[
  'test@t-online.de',
  'kontakt@test.de',
  'info@test.de',
  'test@gmx.de',
  'kontakt@test.de',
]
```

I want to check for duplicates and save the list in a txt file with one email in each line. The final result would be in this case:

```
      test@t-online.de
      kontakt@test.de
      info@test.de
      test@gmx.de
```

fs.writeFileSync('./results/test.txt', list)

How to do that?

Comment: `[...(new Set(list))].join('\n')` <-- this should give you unique emails separated by new-line (ie, `\n`).

Comment: To write using writeFileSync, please try `fs.writeFileSync('./results/test.txt', [...(new Set(list))].join('\n'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code. I have used `"a"` flag to append the data in same file

```
let fs = require('fs');

let data = [
    'test@t-online.de',
    'kontakt@test.de',
    'info@test.de',
    'test@gmx.de',
    'kontakt@test.de',
];
let stream = fs.createWriteStream("emails.txt", {'flags': 'a'});
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
    // this will remove duplicates from the array
    const result = data.filter((item, pos) => data.indexOf(item) === pos)
    result.forEach(email => stream.write(email + '\n'));
});
```

Comment: thanks! How would the code look like if the text file already has addresses and we want to add the email addresses after the last line?

Comment: You mean appending new emails to same file ? Then above code should work

Answer (score 1):

You can perform that by performing a loop through the Array if emails and perform a filter to like bellow

```js
let emails = [
  'test@t-online.de',
  'kontakt@test.de',
  'info@test.de',
  'test@gmx.de',
  'kontakt@test.de',
];

let result = emails.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if(accumulator.indexOf(current) ===  -1){
    accumulator = accumulator.concat(current);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `list` with `[...(new Set(list))].join('\n')`

- `new Set()` ensures only duplicates are removed and only unique elements remain.
- `join('\n')` transforms the Array into a string separated by new-line (`\n`) character.

```js
const list = [
  'test@t-online.de',
  'kontakt@test.de',
  'info@test.de',
  'test@gmx.de',
  'kontakt@test.de',
];
console.log([...(new Set(list))].join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

for removing duplicated emails:

```
arr = [...new Set(arr)];
```

for writing

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./results/test.txt');
writeStream.on('error', function(e) { 
  /* handel error here */ 
});
arr.forEach(email => writeStream.write(email + '\n'));
writeStream.end();
```

**To append data to an existed file**
Create write stream in append mode

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./results/test.txt', { 'flags': 'a', 'encoding': null, 'mode': 0666});
```

refer [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/fs.html#fs.createWriteStream)

Comment: thanks for you answer, it says file not defined

Comment: @MarcelDz I have updated the code, I use the wrong variable name. Sorry

Comment: thanks! How would the code look like if the text file already has addresses and we want to add the email addresses after the last line?

Comment: fs.createWriteStream('./results/test.txt', { 'flags': 'a', 'encoding': null, 'mode': 0666}) should work. the flag 'a' do the magic. You can refer to the docs here https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/fs.html#fs.createWriteStream